# Copy file on Google Drive

Tags: ios, google-drive

On my iPhone, how can I copy/duplicate a file on Google Drive? I tried the apps (drive/docs), and also the web interface but I find no such feature. I remember giving the drive app a one star rating for this some years ago. Still not fixed?

Comment: This question is about the computer software Google Drive. How can it be more on topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the feature after someone posted the answer on Twitter. The feature exists buried in the Documents app. Tap the three dots to bring up Share etc menu, in it there is the Make a copy feature. Perfect, but too cleverly hidden. This feature should definitely exist in the Drive app, because I guess Google would have to implement the feature with every application for each file type like spreadsheets and so on.